# How can I use two Audio Listeners?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem is that I have a character controller the player with a camera and the camera have a Audio Listener.

But I also have another camera the Main Camera that also have a Audio Listener.
The Main Camera is using Cinemachine Brain and using virtual cameras.

If I disable the Audio Listener on the Main Camera the character in my cut scene will walk to a door/s but when the door/s will open there will be no sound of the door open.

And if I disable the player controller camera Audio Listener then when I will move my player around to door/s there will be no sound when the player enter a door.
And I need both to work. While the character in the cut scene is walking and enter a door and the door is open the player can walk around.

Screenshot of the player controller camera and the audio listener:

[image: Audio Listener player controller camera]

And this is the Main Camera Audio Listener screenshot:

[image: Main Camera Audio Listener]

So now when running the game the character medea_m_arrebola is walking by animation through a door and there is a sound of the door open and close.
This is part of a cut scene that work in the background I mean the cut scene camera is not enabled yet but you can hear the audio.

Later I will switch between the cameras to show parts of the cut scene.

But now also the FPSController ( Player ) is working and the player can move around but when he will walk through a door the door will open but there will be no audio sound of the door.

And if I will enable both Audio Listeners I will get this warning message in the console in the editor say that more then 2 audio listeners are enabled....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a design issue to me. Unity can only handle one AudioListener at a time. You basically have to construct your cutscene-system to work with what Unity offers, or find some kind of workaround to fit your specific case.

You could try to **en-/disable your AudioListeners on the fly** or maybe use **AudioSources around you player dedicated to directional audio input** while in a cutscene. (Like a surround sound setup with empty objects) That way you could simulate two AudioListeners. The best case would be if you **reworked your system** to use one AudioListener for both inputs.

Maybe try a workaround first but if it does not 100% work as intended do the rework. It's worth it in the long run.

Comment: Switching audio listeners is not good since I need to hear the doors open/close at the same time when controlling the player and the other character is walking somewhere else in the scene ( Not far from the player but out of the player view ). For some reason the Audio Listener on the player camera prevent from doors to play audio when other character walk through the doors. Maybe the problem is that the other character that walk through a door is used by virtual cameras for follow and look at ? The main camera is used with cinemachine and timeline.

Comment: That might be your problem. Maybe try to set your main cameras position to the door during the cutscene to confirm that

Comment: For testing I disabled both Audio Listeners on the player camera and the main camera and created a new empty gameobject and added to it a new audio listener. Now when running the game I hear the character walking through the door I hear the door open and close but when moving the player through a door I don't hear the door open/close.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between those two situations? Walking the player works, thats great! But what are you refering to when you say 'move' and what exactly is different compared to walking the player?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand it correctly yet. If I put audio listener for example on one camera for example the player camera in this case FPSCamera and the audio listener is enabled.  So everything that is close to this camera will be heard but far objects or characters will not ? The audio listener in the game is like a microphone ? This is the idea ? So if I enable the audio listener on the player camera I hear the doors the player open since the audio listener is on the player? And if I enable the audio listener only on other character then I will hear only close things to that character ?

Comment: And for my cut scene the idea the main goal is to do like in games that the player can move and have control but then he hear from the distance someone getting closer someone is walking and getting closer and at this time I want to switch the cameras and show the character that is coming closer to the player. Since I added the character that is coming closer audio source and playing steps I hear the character walking but the I don't hear the door open/close. The idea is also to hear the door open/close and make this a signal to the player that someone is getting closer.

Comment: I didn't make one cut scene animation. I made that when running the game the character that is getting closer to the player start walking automatic using animatior and HumanoidWalk animation. And using cinemachine cameras. But in my scene first when running the game it start when the player have the control and the player camera is enabled and the cinemachine main camera is disabled. This way I want to make the effect the idea that someone is coming closer.

Comment: I will record a short very short video clip of my game to show what I mean.

Comment: Yes! Exactly that! It works just like a virtual microphone. But the AudioListener component has no range built in. The range from where you start to hear sound is entirely dependent on the **AudioSources**. Check out the `Max Distance` option in the Unity manual regarding AudioSources: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html)
If you want your audio to be heard over greater distance the just give the range a little bump.

Comment: Sorry for the all the mess and problems. It's working fine. Thank you.